# List of buttons?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, ui-design

I've been working on a small program which gets a list of url's from the web server ( latest forum topics ) and warns the user whenever a new topic is created.

So the main form of my program have a list of buttons. Each button has the text of the forum topic and extra information below. Opens the browser with the topics url when user presses.

The problem is, creating buttons for every topic doesn't feel right. I'm sure there is a better way to create a user interface for this program. I tried listview but I need space for some extra information so one line and one text-size isn't good for it.

edit: I'm sorry, it's a windows form app.

Comment: What plataform are you using? (ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF)

Comment: judging from the way the question is worded, sounds like you're using WinForms, and it sounds like you could really use WPF (especially since this is a small program, if you're not too familiar with WPF).  Basically, I say this because you can add the clicking/open the browser functionality to many different kinds of controls, and you can custom tailor a composite control very easily to play around with the presentation and style of the control.  It wouldn't have to be just a ListView or just a group of buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net). Here's what can be done with it:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/_images/task-list.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of thing I would look at WPF and style my own controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through them and add the buttons and labels programmatically. Placing them vertically below eachother is simple math.

Probably not best practice, but it has always worked for me.